# AllowHtml doesn't work with Array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes

I use the AllowHtml attribute in my ASP.NET MVC project but it doesn't work with an array in my view model. If the property isn't an array the attribute works. And now, I can't validate my html tags.

Any suggestion?
Thank you

`[AllowHtml]`

```
public string[] ContentText { get; set; }
```

Error:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will not work with arrays . ***It must be a simple string property for this to work***.  What you can do is

```
public class ContentText { [AllowHtml]public string Text { get; set; } }
```

and then have you main model take a collection of this `ContentText` as property:

```
public class ContentTextCollection { public ContentText [] Texts { get; set; } }
```